# easy partial fraction decomposition of complex fraction

Tags: complex-numbers, partial-fractions

I should make a partial fraction decomposition of the following fraction
where $z\in \mathbb{C} $. I am not able to start or do something because I am not able to factorize $z²+4$. Does anybody has any suggestions??

$$\frac{1}{z^{2}+4}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $z^2+4=(z+2i)(z-2i)$. You can use the normal formula for the roots of a quadratic equation and use that $\sqrt{-1}=i$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not able to see this by myself :-)

Comment: Make sure that you understand how to find roots of a quadratic equation. If you understand that, it is straightforward to see that this formula still holds for complex quadractic equations.